# Javascript Forms

Tags: javascript, forms

I something weird going on with my javascript code.  I have a very very simple form that returns a javascript function called validate.  Basically the function checks to see if the box is empty, if it is, it marks the box yellow.

My problem is, when I click the button with nothing in the box, it just refreshed the page and brings me to the top of the page.  I have put alerts in the function and it actually changes the color of the box, but after I click ok on the alert, the page refreshes.  Here is the code I have.

Here is the form in the body of the HTML:

```
<form id="theform" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate('theform');">


<input type="text" name="food" value="" style="width: 160px" />


 <input type="submit" value="submit" />

   </form>
```

and Here is the javascript that is in the Head of the HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(formName) {

        var theform = document.getElementById(formName);


     if (theform.food.value == "") {

            theform.food.style.background = "yellow";

        }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: your event registration is equivalent to `return validate(this.id)`, you can get rid of `getElementById` completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the validation fails you need to return false so that the form doesn't get submitted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(formName) {
        var theform = document.getElementById(formName);
        if (theform.food.value == "") {
            theform.food.style.background = "yellow";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your function runs `onsubmit`, when the function is finished it will submit. You don't have an `action` defined on your form, so it just reloads the page. If you wish for the form to not submit, just `return false` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly return false for the submit action to be canceled.

(Only if `food.value` is empty, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

```
onsubmit="function(){validate('theform');return false};"
```